# Unable to connect to my HDInsight cluster using Hive ODBC

Tags: excel, hive, odbc, azure-hdinsight

Using the `Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver DSN Setup`, I am trying to connect to my HDInsight cluster, so I can import a Hive table to an Excel sheet. Everything Excel is setup correctly, so I am not worried about that. My issue is that when I click on Test,

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

Reads "`Failed to establish connection SQLSTATE: HY000[Microsoft][HiveODBC] (34) Error from Hive: Could not resolve host for client socket..`"

My username and password is both correct, because I can sign into the `HDInsight Query Console` without any hiccups.

Can you help please?

Comment: Ok. this time it connected, but I had to enable Remote Desktop for my cluster. Understandable. Now, in Excel, under Data tab. I click on External data -> From other sources -> From Data Connection Wizard -> ODBC DSN -> <my Data source (hive_test)> I this the same window as the first screenshot, and I have to input my Password, which throws the same `TESTS COMPLETED WITH ERROR` error. Please help!!

Comment: See this article (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-connect-excel-hive-odbc-driver/). Not certain, but it looks like the https:// portion of the host name is superfluous, try removing that.

Comment: When an application requests a "host name", then you must enter a host name. Not an URL. For your information, Hive drivers use Thrift binary protocol by default, not HTTP.

Comment: Well, then I am guessing the Azure Documentation (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-connect-excel-hive-odbc-driver/) is perhaps wrong. Besides, using just the Hostname (`nkhlHDI` this time), I get the same error.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it matters, but when I `ping nkhlHDI.azurehdinsight.net`, the request times out (all four).

Answer (score 0):

The `hostname` property field should be in this format:
clusterdnsname.azurehdinsight.net

In your case, it should be `nkhlHDI.azurehdinsight.net`.

Ping to your server name times out is expected.